# TIME column in TOP command for mysql

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, top

When I run top on my database server I get that mysqld has been running for 4:00.51 and it continues to go up.

I assume this means that one process with mysql has been running this long from other posts on here. Its not set to cumulative mode as best I can tell as the heading looks like it would change to CTIME if that be the case.

What I'm wondering is if this is normal for a site that makes a lot of individual connections using PHP. I shouldn't have any long running processes that would hold on to a mysql connection for this long, only seconds at most.

Am I incorrect to assume that this time relates to one connection/process running? I think usually I see it flash up and away on the TOP, not just stay there with this number increasing.

Answer (score 1):

When you look at `top` and see `mysqld`, **there should only be one `mysqld` per instance**. Older versions of server-compiled `mysqld` spawn many threads. I'll assume you are not using such.

To see individual connections you could do one of two things

In mysql client, run `SHOW PROCESSLIST;` (Source of incoming connection in the third column `Host`)

In the OS, run

- `netstat | grep -i mysql`
- `netstat | grep 3306`

For emphasis, **you should only see one `mysqld` process per instance**.

If you want to double check the time value as seen in top, ask mysqld

If you have MySQL 5.1+, run this:

```
SELECT 
    TRIM(REPLACE(CONCAT(
        IF(dy=0,'',IF(dy=1,'1 day ',CONCAT(dy,' days '))),
        IF(hr=0,'',IF(hr=1,'1 hr ', CONCAT(hr,' hrs  '))),
        IF(mn=0,'',IF(mn=1,'1 min ',CONCAT(mn,' mins '))),
        IF(sc=0,'',IF(sc=1,'1 sec ',CONCAT(sc,' secs ')))),'  ',' '))
    TimeDisplay
FROM (SELECT dy,hr,mn,MOD(sec_aaaa,60) sc
FROM (SELECT dy,hr,FLOOR((sec_aaa - dy*86400 - hr*3600)/60) mn,sec_aaa sec_aaaa
FROM (SELECT dy,FLOOR((sec_aa - (dy*86400))/3600) hr,sec_aa sec_aaa
FROM (SELECT FLOOR(sec_a/86400) dy,sec_a sec_aa
FROM
    (
        SELECT variable_value sec_a
        FROM information_schema.global_status
        WHERE variable_name = 'Uptime'
    )
A) AA) AAA) AAAA) B;
```

If you have MySQL 5.0, run this

```
MYSQL_CONN="-uroot -ppassword"
UPTIME_SEC=`mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -A -N -e"SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Uptime'" | awk '{print $2}'`
SQLTIME="SELECT TRIM(REPLACE(CONCAT("
SQLTIME="${SQLTIME} IF(dy=0,'',IF(dy=1,'1 day ',CONCAT(dy,' days '))),"
SQLTIME="${SQLTIME} IF(hr=0,'',IF(hr=1,'1 hr ', CONCAT(hr,' hrs  '))),"
SQLTIME="${SQLTIME} IF(mn=0,'',IF(mn=1,'1 min ',CONCAT(mn,' mins '))),"
SQLTIME="${SQLTIME} IF(sc=0,'',IF(sc=1,'1 sec ',CONCAT(sc,' secs ')))),'  ',' ')) TimeDisplay"
SQLTIME="${SQLTIME} FROM (SELECT dy,hr,mn,MOD(sec_aaaa,60) sc"
SQLTIME="${SQLTIME} FROM (SELECT dy,hr,FLOOR((sec_aaa - dy*86400 - hr*3600)/60) mn,sec_aaa sec_aaaa"
SQLTIME="${SQLTIME} FROM (SELECT dy,FLOOR((sec_aa - (dy*86400))/3600) hr,sec_aa sec_aaa"
SQLTIME="${SQLTIME} FROM (SELECT FLOOR(sec_a/86400) dy,sec_a sec_aa"
SQLTIME="${SQLTIME} FROM (SELECT ${UPTIME_SEC} sec_a ) A) AA) AAA) AAAA) B"
MYSQL_START_TIME=`mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -A -N -e"${SQLTIME}"`
echo ${MYSQL_START_TIME}
```

This will give you the number of seconds mysqld has been running.

If you want to see the date and time mysqld started

MySQL 5.1+

```
select (now() - interval variable_value second) MySQLStartTime from
information_schema.global_status where variable_name='uptime';
```

MySQL 5.0

```
MYSQL_CONN="-uroot -ppassword"
UPTIME_SEC=`mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -A -N -e"SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Uptime'" | awk '{print $2}'`
MYSQL_START_TIME=`mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -A -N -e"SELECT (NOW() - INTERVAL ${UPTIME_SEC} SECOND) MySQLStartTime"`
echo ${MYSQL_START_TIME}
```

Give it a Try !!!